# Showing that logical forms of these sets can be derived

Tags: discrete-mathematics

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqUZo.jpg

How can I do a similar method with this instead: 
$(A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B) = (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$
 I keep getting a different answer from the solution. Help me, thanks

Comment: The claim is wrong. It should be $(A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B) = (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$.

Comment: For any set $X$, $X \cup X$ is simply $X$. So what you're trying to prove is: $(A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B) = (A \setminus B)$, which doesn't hold.

Consider $A = \{1,2\}$ and $B = \{2,3\}$. Then $(A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B) = \{1,3\}$ but $A \setminus B = \{1\}$

Comment: My bad i made a typo in the commands

Comment: The image you attached also has the same incorrect claim though.

Comment: Oh the image had the wrong equivalency, sorry my friend. I edited my message now. $(A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B) = (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$ is basically what I'm trying to see if the method would work that way as well.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
(A\cup B)\backslash(A\cap B) & = (A\cup B)\cap(\overline{A\cap B}) = (A\cup B)\cap(\overline{A}\cup\overline{B})\\
& = [(A\cup B)\cap\overline{A}]\cup[(A\cup B)\cap\overline{B}]\\
& = [(A\cap\overline{A})\cup(B\cap\overline{A})]\cup[(A\cap\overline{B})\cup(B\cap\overline{B})]\\
& = (B\cap\overline{A})\cup(A\cap\overline{B}) = (B\backslash A)\cup(A\backslash B)
\end{align*}

Comment: I see I forgot about the distributive property in the last line, thank you so much APC89.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Feel free to up vote it if you think it is worthy :)

Comment: I wish I could, my rep isn't enough though sadly :(